# Postgres math: Operator does not exist: bigint == integer

Tags: postgresql

I have the following sql:

```
create table gps (laf int, "timestamp" timestamp);
select * from 
  (select *, row_number() over() from gps) as yo
where row_number == 10
```

But it yields this response:

```
ERROR: operator does not exist: bigint == integer Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts. Position: 84
```

typecasting does not seem to help.  How do I compare row_number (a bigint) with a number?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems I'm stuck in programming land, I needed `=` instead of `==`, but posting here for posterity, and google:

```
select * from 
  (select *, row_number() over() from gps) as yo
where row_number = 0
```